# How to change fullcalendar source in fullcalendar V5

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using full calendar v5.3.0. What I want to do is, I have two sources for the calendar.

1. Initially, when the calendar is displayed for the first time I have to display events from both the sources.
2. I have a  dropdown if it changes after the calendar is loaded then I have to show events from the dropdown source only.
3. If the user changes view type or clicks previous/next then I have to show events from default source only.
   From the above three points, I am done with first and second but I got stuck on the third point. I am unable to figure out how to change the calendar source from the dropdown to default again on view type change or previous/next button click. Following is my code.

Code to load calendar initially

```
     var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
        var Draggable = FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable;
        var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
        new Draggable(containerEl, {
            itemSelector: '.fc-event'
        });
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
            timeZone: 'UTC',
            defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
            navLinks: true, 
            fixedWeekCount: false, 
            weekNumbers: true, 
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
            columnFormat: 'ddd D/M',
            weekNumberTitle: 'Week ', 
            lazyFetching: false, 
            eventBackgroundColor: '#ffdfc2',
            eventBorderColor: 'transparent',
            eventTextColor: '#bf6109',
            displayEventEnd: true,
            showNonCurrentDates: false,
            noEventsMessage: InformationMessages('23'),
            slotDuration: '00:15:00',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            eventSources: [fcSources.default, fcSources.dropdown],
            timeFormat: timeFormatOnSettings,
            slotEventOverlap: false,                
            eventRender: function (info) {
                if (info.view.type === 'timeGridDay') {
                    var time = info.el.querySelector('.fc-time');
                    var span = document.createElement("span");
                    span.className = 'fullcalendar-event-close';
                    var node = document.createTextNode("X");
                    span.appendChild(node);
                    time.appendChild(span);
                    info.el.querySelector(".fullcalendar-event-close").addEventListener("click", function () {
                        info.event.remove();
                    });
                }
            },
            eventDidMount: function (info) {
                if (info.view.type === 'dayGridMonth') {
                    console.log('dayGridMonth');
                }
                if (info.view.type === 'timeGridWeek') {
                    console.log('timeGridWeek');
                }
                if (info.view.type === 'timeGridDay') {
                    console.log('timeGridDay');
                }
            }
        });
        calendar.render();
```

Two sources dropdown and default

```
        var fcSources = {
            dropdown: {
               // dropdownsource code
            },
            default: {
              // defaultsource code
            }
        };
```

Removing all sources on dropdown change and then adding dropdown source only and then refetching the events

```
        $('.js-example-basic-single').change(function () {
            var eventSource = [];
            eventSource = calendar.getEventSources();
            $.each(eventSource, function (key, value) {
                value.remove();
            });
            calendar.addEventSource(fcSources.dropdown);
            calendar.refetchEvents();
        });
```

I tried to change the source using eventDidMount, but it is not firing, console.log() is logging nothing.

Comment: changing the source using eventDidMount makes no sense - that occurs while you're loading events from a source, it's too late then to decide what source to use! These hooks: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-render-hooks run when a view is changed. Beware of infinite loops though, as adding an event source can cause the view to render again, which will cause you to choose the event source again, which would cause the view to render again, etc. Write your code carefully so it doesn't add/remove event sources unnecessarily.

Comment: @ADyson I used viewDidMount hook instead of eventDidMount in the following way but I think this hook is not working for me as I can't see anything in the console after changing the view or on clicking previous/next button. 'viewDidMount: function (arg) {console.log(arg);}'. Is there anything else I need to do with this.

Comment: viewDidMount should work fine like that - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBbMJRv . Note that it only runs when you switch views, not when you press next/prev (because that doesn't require the view to be re-rendered).

Comment: Why do you need to reset the source after ever prev/next though? That sounds annoying for the user. If I, as the user, had used a dropdown to filter the events, I'd expect that to persist until next time I changed the dropdown, not keep getting reset just because I try to browse to another date in the calendar, or view the events in a list instead of a grid. That would be infuriating. I think it's not a good requirement, personally.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the solution. I did that by using datesSet. datesSet is called each time we click on prev/next button or if view type is changed. For more information please visit [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet). Following is my code.

```
datesSet: function (dateInfo) {
                var eventSource = [];
                eventSource = calendar.getEventSources();
                $.each(eventSource, function (key, value) {
                    value.remove();
                });
                calendar.addEventSource(fcSources.default);
                calendar.refetchEvents();
          }
```